# Online source for learning about continued fraction expansions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I started stuying Number Theory,and I'd like to learn about continued fractions,is there anywhere online where I can learn to basics of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to jump right in, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) gets into things in a hurry.  And there are references.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a link to *Continued Fractions* by C. D. Olds](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).